# Is there any way to send a 3-plug RCA audio/video signal to an ipad screen?

Tags: ipad

I have a "Phantom DJI" quadcopter with a lot of upgrades, including a "Fatshark predator" "FPV" system which basically allows me to view VGA quality video, live, from a gopro mounted on the quadcopter. The fatshark comes with a so-so video quality "virtual boy" looking pair of goggles that doubles as the receiver itself.

This headset/receiver has a 1/16th inch 3 ring RCA A/V output jack that can go to a video monitor. The kit includes a cable which can be plugged into a traditional RCA jack setup.

So my question is, is there *any* way to transmit rca video signal to an ipad? For example, one or more "proxies" as a solution could be reasonable. Transmitting the last leg to the ipad via some internet protocol may work for example.

The appeal of using the ipad is that it is a high resolution battery powered monitor which I *already own*. I'll be in the field with this thing and the portability is of particular interest.

I consider solutions requiring jailbreaking reasonable answers though this is not preferred for obvious reasons. Also, low cost android tablet solutions are equally reasonable. I've already ordered an RCA-to-hdmi converter which should arrive shortly.

Comment: I looked for the question on Ask Different but no dice. I don't have a really solid solution for you; it's more of a workaround:

First, connect the RCA video signal to a PC then use an app called AirDisplay to connect your iPad as a second PC monitor over ad-hoc wifi (link below). 

http://avatron.com/apps/air-display

Comment: So you can't use the same interface app with the fatshark that idj provides for the iPhone/iPad for the standard camera?